# Type conversion (typecasting). Convert array to matrix (C code to Visual Basic)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, casting, vb6

I am working at rewriting C code to Visual Basic now. And I got some problems with this syntaxes:

C code:

```
typedef uint8_t state_t[4][4];
static state_t* state;

void myFunc (uint8_t* output)
{
    state = (state_t*)output;
    // some actions
}
```

My Visual Basic code:

```
Dim state(3, 3) As Byte

Sub myVBFunc(ByRef output() As Byte)
    state = output  ' does not work: Cannot convert Byte() to Byte(*,*)'
    'state = CType(output, Byte(,)) ''also does not work'

    ' some actions'
End Sub
```

I can do it in C, because array name is a pointer to the first element. And C can automatically converts this types. So VB cannot. I'm stacked here.

**How to convert this array to matrix?
Or how to avoid using of this in VB?**

P.S. Actually I work in Visual Basic 6.0. (try to modify old project).

Comment: Did you try changing `output()` to `output(,)`?

Comment: Typecasting and -conversion are different things.

Comment: @ProGrammer In Main function output will be array (one-dimensional), If I change it here, function will compile, but can it be possible to use this function for my 1D array?

Comment: Note: Your cast in the C code violates effective type rule. It invokes UB. And "because array name is a pointer to the first element" is wrong.

Comment: @Olaf I read about conversion and casting. You are right, but still "In the C family of languages and ALGOL 68, the word cast typically refers to an explicit type conversion" (wiki). By the way I try to find any working solution. If you will give me an example how to solve my problem using `casting` it will be ok!

About second note: so I have to avoid using this type conversion in C? and AFTER that translate code to VB? But It works now :(

Can you clarify what's wrong with array name and pointer? It is something new to me!

Comment: @Mikhail_Sam: That is clearly wrong for C++ for certain casts and wrong for pointer casts, which don't convert the pointed object and can invoke UB, as I noted above. Not to forget that conversions can be implicit, casts never. "Works now" is a bad criterion to deduce C code is compliant. If your exploit UB, this can change with any change of the code, compiler/-version, optimisation level, weather, run, etc. Please read a good C book for the rest. This is basic stuff and has been handled here and elsewhere a (ca.) thousand times already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used simple way: just assign it trough the loop using index multiplication.

```
For k = 0 To 3
     For j = 0 To 3
        state(k, j) = temp(4 * k + j)
     Next j
Next k
```

---

Why I didn't use [Guillermo Phillips's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511016/4960953):

**a.** I can't replace `state(3,3)` from my question just as

```
Dim state() As Byte
```

because there is some specific math here which is really simple for matrices.
I found useful `ReDim` option. Especially when use it in this way:

```
ReDim Preserve input(15)
```

It saves previous values of `input` array or put zeros in new positions!
But we can convert array to matrix using `ReDim`:

> ReDim cannot change the number of dimensions

**b.** Idea of using of user defined type is really interesting but I stall can't figure out how to assign then `Byte()` to my

```
Type type_state
    state(3, 3) As Byte
End Type
```

**c.** Agree! This way is useful. I just avoid it because of it's complicity (much easier to create function with inbuilt loop). But maybe using object is more safety?..

Comment: I'm glad I put you on the right path. About ReDim look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx especially in the Remarks section. You can ALWAYS ReDim an uninitialised dynamic array to have ANY number of dimensions you like. And you can always ReDim the last dimension of a dynamic array.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about VB6, then you have three options:

a. Change everything to use dynamic arrays:

```
Dim state() As Byte

Sub myVBFunc(ByRef output() As Byte)
    state = output 
End Sub
```

You can set up the array to call myVBFunc by redimensioning e.g.:

```
Dim myarray() as Byte

ReDim myarray(3,3)

myVBFunc(myarray)
```

b. Embed the fixed size array in a user defined type and pass that around instead:

```
Type type_state
    state(3, 3) As Byte
End Type

Dim state As type_state

Sub test()
    Dim something As type_state

    myVBFunc something
End Sub


Sub myVBFunc(ByRef output As type_state)
    state = output
End Sub
```

c. Use objects. Set up a class to hold your fixed sized array and set up getters and setters to access it. A short answer would be to long for me to show in this post.

(You will need extra code to set up the array itself)

Comment: I add my own answer with some points about your method. Thank you for help!

Comment: Just to make it clear, the reason you can't copy a dynamic array to a fixed sized array directly, is that the memory layout is different. But you can copy one dynamic array to another, as the memory layout is the same. Unfortunately, VB6 doesn't allow you to pass fixed sized arrays to functions, but it does allow you to pass UDTs.

Comment: I define all array as dynamic (`Dim someArray() As Byte`) and pass it to functions. As I understand I can pass them already initialized with some length or just defined and use `ReDim` already inside of this function.